# Elasticsearch 6.1 multi index search with nested fields issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I run a multi index search (elasticsearch 6.1.1) in 2 indexes with nested field,

"uniqueID" is a nested field that exist only in person index.

"pobox" is a nested field that exist only in adress index

I am getting error:

"index": "adress", "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [uniqueID]"

"index": "person", "[nested] nested object under path [pobox] is not of nested type"

In my query I search in person index for field uniqueID, why I am getting error for pobox field that exist only in adress index. Same for search in adress index it look for uniqueId field that exist only in person index

POST http://locahost:9200/person,adress/_search

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "person"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "uniqueID",
                  "query": {
                    "span_near": {
                      "clauses": [
                        {
                          "span_term": {
                            "uniqueID.uniqueID.auto": "1"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "slop": 3,
                      "in_order": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "adress"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "pobox",
                  "query": {
                    "span_near": {
                      "clauses": [
                        {
                          "span_term": {
                            "pobox.pobox.auto": "1"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "slop": 3,
                      "in_order": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```js
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: { my_query }",
                "index_uuid": "9Z0W-P9ZS02kJ7WmOKHPVQ",
                "index": "adress"
            },
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: { my_query }",
                "index_uuid": "EHoxKGhdSmKoYdNgsylotw",
                "index": "person"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "adress",
                "node": "AEhiq0wvQTGh468sSmDN5g",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to create query: { my_query }",
                    "index_uuid": "9Z0W-P9ZS02kJ7WmOKHPVQ",
                    "index": "adress",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                        "reason": "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [uniqueID]"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "person",
                "node": "AEhiq0wvQTGh468sSmDN5g",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to create query: { my_query }",
                    "index_uuid": "EHoxKGhdSmKoYdNgsylotw",
                    "index": "person",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                        "reason": "[nested] nested object under path [pobox] is not of nested type"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: "pobox" exist in both indexes, in adress index is nested and in person index is string.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the nested structure you try to query on one index doesn't exist on the other, so what do you expect?

IMO you should split the queries up and use [_msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) if you always need those together.